# Intent from Fragment to a MapsActivity from onCreateView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-maps

this is my code of my third tab in which i have put a button to intent from this current fragment to my MapsActivity, but as soon as i click my button, the app stops running.

This is my code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment


    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab3, container, false);

    mapbtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.mapButton);

    mapbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return v;

}
```

Please someone help!!!

Comment: What does your logcat say?

Comment: provide logcat error

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback, you guys told me to inspect my logcat which suggested that i should take a look at my Android Manifest file and the actual problem was that the API key was declared twice in the metadata tag....Thanks again :) happy coding!!